# SSRS sum of values attached to a group

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has a group. Lets say the report is grouped by state. And within each state, there are cities.

Attached to each state is some statistic I want to sum up. Lets say it is total number of public schools. This information only exists at the state level and does not exist at the individual city level.

Within each state group, I have detail rows that show bunch of information about each city. That detail isn't relevant for this question so I will skip over that.

Now, here is my question. On this report, I need to show bunch of totals. One of the totals I need to show is total number of public schools.

If I just do a regular SUM, it multiplies out the number attached to each state by the number of cities in each state. What I need to do is take a SUM of public schools and count each state just once.

I hope you understood my question.

Comment: Instead of describing the problem, please show us sample data, report layout and what you get when you preview the report..

Comment: Just use either MIN() , MAX() or AVG() instead of SUM()